# Unable to import module in jupyter notebook, but able to import it in the terminal interpreter

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, cygwin

I installed `yfinance` library (from jupyter notebook) and then tried to import it in jupyter notebook. But it did not work. I also tried to uninstall it and install it from terminal. But it still did not work. However I can import other libraries like pandas in . Below is the screen shot of my jupyter notebook:

[image]

However, note that I am able to import the same from terminal:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Comment: You are using outdated advice when installing inside a Jupyter notebook. You shouldn't be using an exclamation point in conjunction with install commands in modern Jupyter. (Google Colab is different.) It should be `%pip install yfinance` for running inside modern Jupyter. And be sure to restart the kernel after running that before trying to import. Open source projects evolve over time and you'll want to consult up-to-date practices. As to why it may not be working... See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) ...

Comment: <continued> about the modern, user-friendly magic install commands added a few years ago to insure installations run from inside an active Jupyter`.ipynb` file get installed to the same environment where the kernel backing the `.ipynb` is running. The exclamation point used in conjunction with an installation command doesn't do that. See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues and confusion like you are seeing.